# Why Cohen-Sutherland algorithm is not appliable on concave polygon?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, concave

My teacher said that Cohen Sutherland algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm cannot be used with concave polygon. I asked him why and he could not give me an answer(I don't why hew works here).

**So I ask You: Why Cohen-Sutherland algorithm is not appliable on concave polygon? What will go wrong?**

Comment: Do you mean [Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm)? Looks like "Cohen Sutherland" is about lines, not polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wikipedia article:

> The algorithm includes, excludes or partially includes the line based
>   on where:
>
> - Both endpoints are in the viewport region (bitwise OR of endpoints == 0): trivial accept.
> - ...

Take a look at the (informal) [definition of convexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set):

> an object is convex if for every pair of points within the object, every point on the straight line segment that joins them is also within the object.

Your teacher may either be talking about scanlines generated from convex polygons, or lines as a special case of a convex polygon.

If the polygon is not convex, concave regions may be drawn as filled in based on the endpoints, as any point along the line is assumed to be part of the polygon. Similar assumptions apply for the other bullet points in the article.

Comment: I a not english and I have to inquire about the answer. The last sentence means that it may treat not filled region as a filled one?

Comment: I can see how that sentence would be confusing. Does it make more sense now that I've edited?

Comment: I can't see how the answer is related to the Cohen-Sutherland algorithm. Don't you think that the teacher was talking about the **viewport itself** being a convex polygon?